# implode with multi variable

Tags: php, implode

```
$inputWhiteJenisPembayaran = $verifikator['whiteJenisPembayaran'];
$dataWhiteJenisPembayaran = array();
foreach ($inputWhiteJenisPembayaran as $bacaDataWhiteJenisPembayaran) {
  if ($bacaDataWhiteJenisPembayaran != "") { //jika inputnya kosong maka tidak akan dieksekusi
    // statement untuk insert data ke database
    $dataWhiteJenisPembayaran[] = $bacaDataWhiteJenisPembayaran;
  }
}
$implodeWhiteJenisPembayaran = implode(", ", $dataWhiteJenisPembayaran);

// whitelist jenis pemasang
$inputWhiteJenisPemasang = $verifikator['whiteJenisPemasang'];
$dataWhiteJenisPemasang = array();
foreach ($inputWhiteJenisPemasang as $bacaDataWhiteJenisPemasang) {
  if ($bacaDataWhiteJenisPemasang != "") { //jika inputnya kosong maka tidak akan dieksekusi
    // statement untuk insert data ke database
    $dataWhiteJenisPemasang[] = $bacaDataWhiteJenisPemasang;
  }
}
$implodeWhiteJenisPemasang = implode(", ", $dataWhiteJenisPemasang);

// whitelist jenis iklan
$inputWhiteJenisIklan = $verifikator['whiteJenisIklan'];
$dataWhiteJenisIklan = array();
foreach ($inputWhiteJenisIklan as $bacaDataWhiteJenisIklan) {
  if ($bacaDataWhiteJenisIklan != "") { //jika inputnya kosong maka tidak akan dieksekusi
    // statement untuk insert data ke database
    $dataWhiteJenisIklan[] = $bacaDataWhiteJenisIklan;
  }
}
$implodeWhiteJenisIklan = implode(", ", $dataWhiteJenisIklan);
```

I want to implode implode result was a $implode_combination_whitelist_blacklist.
I made a coding like this but could not.

```
$implode_combination_whitelist_blacklist = implode(", ", $implodeWhiteJenisPembayaran, $implodeWhiteJenisPemasang, $implodeWhiteJenisIklan);
```

how to become one implodes?

Comment: talking about longVariableNames.... eh? ;) but in all seriousness, i am finding it harder to read and track.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
$implode_combination_whitelist_blacklist = implode(", ", array_merge($implodeWhiteJenisPembayaran, $implodeWhiteJenisPemasang, $implodeWhiteJenisIklan));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it makes sense to store your filtered data in 3 different arrays (imploding each) then merge them and implode them again.  Just declare a single/master result array and push values into it as you loop each subarray of `$verifikator`.

This seems more direct:

```
$result = array();

foreach($verifikator['whiteJenisPembayaran'] as $v) {
  if ($v != "") {
    // statement untuk insert data ke database
    $result[] = $v;
  }
}

foreach ($verifikator['whiteJenisPemasang'] as $v) {
  if ($v != "") {
    // statement untuk insert data ke database
    $result[] = $v;
  }
}

foreach ($verifikator['whiteJenisIklan'] as $v) {
  if ($v != "") {
    // statement untuk insert data ke database
    $result[] = $v;
  }
}

$implode_combination_whitelist_blacklist = implode(", ",$result);
```